Evolution: send meeting invitations automatically
When I need to invite people to a meeting I do the following:

Open a new meeting dialogue in one of the calendars
Add e-mail addresses of the invites
Set description and location
Close and Save
Right-click on the meeting and select "Forward as iCalendar"
Send e-mail to invitees

Is there any way for steps 5 and 6 to happen automatically? I often forget them.

In Evolution, you can streamline the process of sending meeting invitations automatically by adjusting your settings to send invites when you save the event.
Try this:

Open Evolution
Go to the Calendar view.
Click on Edit in the menu and choose Preferences.
Select the Calendar and Tasks section from the list on the left.
Under General settings, look for the option that says Automatically send meeting requests and updates.
Enable this option.

When you create and save a meeting with invitees, the invitations should automatically be sent via email without needing to manually forward the event as an iCalendar. This will eliminate the need for steps 5 and 6.

I can't find that option in the General panel.
